React application is reloading page after api response
On button click
After making python api call, react application is getting reloaded.
tried adding e.preventDefault still no luck
app.py returns below code
return jsonify({"file_path": file_path})

From react calls tried like below
const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload_images', {
            images: imageFilesArray
        });

        console.log('Upload successful:', response.data);

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/rewrite_json", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));


Hello can you add the code where you call those function ?
Also if your using axios you don't need fetch anymore !

There is not enough context here. We need the whole component code. My guess is you have incorrectly bound the python API call to the button click instead of onSubmit of the containing form. The handler needs to be onSubmit of the form. The button should have no click handler. Just type="submit". Then inside the submit handler, that's where you do e.preventDefault(). It is only effective on submit event.

Found the issue.
As I am updating the same folder with dynamically generated content files, as the folder got updated, the local application is re-rendering.
My python code is creating and storing a dynamically created file into the same project folder.
in local it rerenders.
